# Импорт CSV в Mongodb и преобразование массива

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

Как можно импортировать файл csv в MongoDB, чтобы повторяющиеся параметры сгруппировались в массив. Уже всё перепробовал,ничего не получается.
Ниже пример. Есть CSV файл с 30000 записей.

- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5 дв., Бензин,Механическая,1.8
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5 дв., Бензин,Механическая,1.9
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5 дв., Бензин,Механическая,2.2
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5 дв., Бензин,Механическая,3.2
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5 дв.,
  Бензин,Автоматическая,3.2
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5       дв.,
  Дизель,Механическая,1.9
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5    дв.,
  Дизель,Механическая,2.4
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5    дв.,
  Дизель,Автоматическая,2.4
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал    5 дв.,
  Дизель,Механическая,2
- Alfa Romeo,159, (2005-2011), Универсал 5    дв.,
  Дизель,Автоматическая,1.9
- Alfa Romeo,164, I Рестайлинг       (1992-1998), Седан,
  Бензин,Механическая,3
- Alfa Romeo,164, I       Рестайлинг (1992-1998), Седан,
  Бензин,Автоматическая,3
- Alfa       Romeo,164, I Рестайлинг (1992-1998), Седан,
  Бензин,Механическая,2
- Alfa Romeo,164, I Рестайлинг (1992-1998), Седан,
  Бензин,Механическая,2.5
- Alfa Romeo,164, I Рестайлинг (1992-1998),       Седан,
  Дизель,Механическая,2.5
- Alfa Romeo,164, I (1987-1992), Седан,     Бензин,Механическая,2
- Alfa Romeo,164, I (1987-1992), Седан,       Бензин,Механическая,3
- Alfa Romeo,164, I (1987-1992), Седан,       Бензин,Автоматическая,3
- Alfa Romeo,164, I (1987-1992), Седан,       Дизель,Механическая,2.5

Необходимо вставить это в Mongodb как

```
        mark: { "Alfa Romeo" },
          models: [
            {
              model: { "159" },
              generations: [
                {
                  generation: { "(2005-2011)" },
                    bodies: [
                    {
                      body: { "Универсал 5 дв." },
                      engines: [
                        {
                          engine: { "Бензин" },
                          transmissions: [
                            {
                              transmission: { "Механическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.8", "1.9", "2.2", "3.2"]
                            },
                            {
                              transmission: { "Автоматическая" },
                              capacity: ["3.2"]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                            {
                          engine: { "Дизель" },
                          transmissions: [
                            {
                              transmission: { "Механическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.9", "2", "2.4"]
                            },
                            {
                              transmission: { "Автоматическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.9", "2.4"]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              model: { "164" },
              generations: [
                {
                  generation: { "I Рестайлинг (1992-1998)" },
                    bodies: [
                    {
                      body: { "Седан" },
                      engines: [
                        {
                          engine: { "Бензин" },
                          transmissions: [
                            {
                              transmission: { "Механическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.8", "1.9", "2.2", "3.2"]
                            },
                            {
                              transmission: { "Автоматическая" },
                              capacity: ["3.2"]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                            {
                          engine: { "Дизель" },
                          transmissions: [
                            {
                              transmission: { "Механическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.9", "2", "2.4"]
                            },
                            {
                              transmission: { "Автоматическая" },
                              capacity: ["1.9", "2.4"]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет. Я уже пробовал и mongoimport, и Studio 3T

Answer (score 0):

Есть чудесный инструмент [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), который обладает фантастическими способностями.

Нужно [превратить CSV в JSON через jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663187/csv-to-json-using-jq), а затем перестроить его структуру в требуемую.

### 1. Добавить названия полей в CSV

Первой строкой в CSV нужно добавить названия полей, они будут преобразованы в ключи `JSON`:

```
mark,model,generation,body,engine,transmission,capacity
```

### 2. Создать фильтр в файле `cars.jq`

Думаю, что можно сделать фильтр меньше, но вот рабочий вариант:

```
# Преобразование в JSON
[
  [
    split("\n")[]                  # transform csv input into array
  | split(",")                     # where first element has key names
  | select(length==7)              # and other elements have values
  ]
  | {h:.[0], v:.[1:][]}            # {h:[keys], v:[values]}
  | [.h, (.v|map(ltrimstr(" ")|tonumber?//.))]   # [ [keys], [values] ]
  | [ transpose[]                  # [ [key,value], [key,value], ... ]
      | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}     # [ {"key":key, "value":value}, ... ]
    ]
  | from_entries                   # { key:value, key:value, ... }
]
# Переделка структуры
| group_by({ mark }) | map({
    mark: .[0].mark,
    models: map({
        model: .model,
        generation: .generation,
        body: .body,
        engine: .engine,
        transmission: .transmission,
        capacity: .capacity
    })
      | group_by({ model }) | map({
          model: .[0].model,
          generations: map({
              generation: .generation,
              body: .body,
              engine: .engine,
              transmission: .transmission,
              capacity: .capacity
          })
          | group_by({ generation }) | map({
              generation: .[0].generation,
              bodies: map({
                  body: .body,
                  engine: .engine,
                  transmission: .transmission,
                  capacity: .capacity
              })
              | group_by({ body }) | map({
                  body: .[0].body,
                  engines: map({
                      engine: .engine,
                      transmission: .transmission,
                      capacity: .capacity
                  })
                  | group_by({ engine }) | map({
                      engine: .[0].engine,
                      transmissions: map({
                          transmission: .transmission,
                          capacity: .capacity
                      })
                      | group_by({ transmission }) | map({
                          transmission: .[0].transmission,
                          capacity: map(.capacity)
                      })
                  })

              })
          })
      })
})
```

### 3. Применить фильтр

```
jq -s -R -f cars.jq cars.csv > cars.json
```

На выходе получатся данные в нужном формате.

### 4. Импорт в MongoDB

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db cars --collection cars --file cars.json
```

Comment: Не получается выполнить команду. Пишет следующую ошибку F:\>jq-win64.exe jq -s -R -f cars.jq cars.csv > cars.json
jq-win64.exe: Could not open jq: No such file or directory. У меня Windows 7 64x

Comment: @VitalYarosh, попробуйте убрать `jq`: `jq-win64.exe -s -R -f cars.jq cars.csv > cars.json`.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)) Только русский язык выводится вопросиками  {
   
            "generation": "I (XK; XL; XM; XP) (1960-1966)",
            "bodies": [
              {
                "body": "�����",
                "engines": [
                  {
                    "engine": "������",
                    "transmissions": [
                      {
                        "transmission": "������������",
                        "capacity": [
                          "2.4",
                          "2.8"

Comment: @VitalYarosh Значит где-то неверная кодировка. В исходном файле какая?